# countdown timer in javascript not showing in my browser even though no error shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, countdowntimer

Please friends i need your help. My javascript countdown timer is not displaying at all in my browser even though it ran without any errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Javascript Countdown Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#getting-started")
            .countdown("2017/01/01", function (event) {
     $(this).text(
       event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
     );
 });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="getting-started"></div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're missing `document.ready`, or you have to move the script below the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the library jQuery countdown, which is missing in your scripts, after this if it's not working yet then try use `$( document ).ready` for your javascript code to execute once your html has finished loading

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#getting-started")
    .countdown("2017/01/01", function (event) {
$(this).text(
event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much it worked. Please, also i need your help i want to display a text for example: "Auction Ended" when it gets to the end of the countdown date in my gridview in asp.net. Thanks

Comment: Please post a different question for this issue and send me the link, I'll have a look

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the link for the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881223/javascript-countdown-timer-not-showing-in-gridview