# javascript countdown timer not showing in gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, countdowntimer

I have implemented this javascript with a hard coded date and it is displaying properly, I have tried it in a griview but it is rather showing the enddate from my database without showing the countdown, but i want to be getting the enddate from the database: Also, when the countdown is over it should display a message: "Project over" Please friends help me out.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.countdown.js"></script>


                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CountDown" ItemStyle-Width="300px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div id="myCountdownClass"><%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("EndDate").ToString()) ? Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("EndDate")).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") : "" %></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.myCountdownClass').each(function () {
                    var date = $(this).text();
                    $(this).countdown(date, function (event) {
                        $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified `id` in your template, but you're trying to select a class in your javascript (`$('.myCountdownClass')`). Change this:

```
<div id="myCountdownClass">
```

to this:

```
<div class="myCountdownClass">
```

Here's the working example (check `script.js` file):

http://embed.plnkr.co/uffoqIjhqvvV7lzFlmzu/

Comment: Tnx for your response. I have changed 'id' to 'class' yet it is not displaying. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check your console. Check if your selector works and selects any elements `console.log($('.myCountdownClass'))`

Comment: Tnk u for ur response. no selector was found. what do i do sir?

Comment: Check your output HTML. There's a problem in your template. I don't know where exactly. You only showed a tiny part of it.

Comment: Thank you sir. No selector was found. What do i do sir? I did just that with the javascript i used hard coded date no errors and a selector was found.

Comment: It is not working sir. But the hard coded date works sir. I want to get the date programmatically.

Comment: Do you want to get current date programatically? Or which date?

Comment: I want to get the end date for each project in my database. I am getting the date already as it shows in my gridview. but the countdown does not show. But if i fix a hard coded date in my javascript it works.

Comment: This is the sample of the hard coded date that works: <div id="getting-started"></div><script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#getting-started")
                .countdown("2020/12/01", function (event) {
                    $(this).text(
                    event.strftime('%Y Years %-m Months %-d days %-w Weeks %-H h %M min %S sec')
                    );
                });
        });
    </script>

Comment: @IkechukwuNwankwo I've updated my answer above with the link to plunkr. Code there works. Please check it.

Comment: @IkechukwuNwankwo if it's not working then FOR SURE you have a problem with the format of your dates in `.myCountdownClass` element. So check them. If not then it's something out of the scope of this question. Please mark my answer as a complete. I helped you as much as I could :)

Comment: You are indeed great. Please, i want to show a label message "Expired" after the countdown date. Can you help me out?